# VirtualBox command-line - setting up port forwarding

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I know how to configure NAT-based port forwarding using the VirtualBox graphical interface (as in the example below).

How can I do the same via the command line?

[image: Port forwarding via VirtualBox GUI]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the machine is powered off, you may use the [`modifyvm`](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm) command:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,2222,,22"
```

If it's powered on, [`controlvm`](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-controlvm).

Comment: Thanks for the `natfp<nic number>` on `controlvm`. That helps automating the setup of my VMs.

Answer (score 7):

On VirtualBox 6+, `--natpf1` is not supported. @Lyndsy Simon's answer has just one change (`--natpf1` is just changed to simply `natpf1`). Changed command looks like this:

```
VBoxManage controlvm "VM name" natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,2222,,22"
```

Obviously I am making a change in the running VM so I used `controlvm`. If the VM is power off mode, use `modifyvm` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Now, with VirtualBox 7+, the command-line changed again. It is:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --nat-pf1="guestssh,tcp,,2222,,22"
```